# Calculating parallel efficiency

Tags: performance, parallel-processing

When calculating parallel efficiency of a program running on a multi-core home PC using the equation:

```
Efficiency = Speedup / p
```

Would `p` represent the number of threads used in the program or the number of cores of the PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, parallel efficiency is computed as Speedup / p where p represents the number of cores. Indeed, in a normal set-up, you are limited by the actual number of cores, not the number of threads.